# How to poll scm using Jenkins for release tags

Tags: jenkins, github

I need a help to poll scm using Jenkins for release tags. Webhook trigger is not working as the Jenkins resides behind the firewall.
Jenkins build has to be triggered if there is a `release/release` tag is committed/pushed under `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/releases`
I have configured the below under Source Code Management tab in Jenkins.
Git ->
Under Repositories, given Repository URL and Credentials. Also under "Advanced" for "Refspec" configured the values as:
`+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*`

Also for Branches to build -> **/tags/**

Configured SCM poll to run for every 5 minutes. Under "Git Polling Log", its polling every 5 minutes and bringing the release details based on the tag. But the Jenkins job is not triggered.Can anyone please help me to address this issue?

From Git Polling Log:

```
Started on 13 Oct, 2020 4:42:00 PM
Polling SCM changes on master
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 2f3a23888bdce0b4ac63044c00f71adedc0aa175 (origin/tags/fb-bin1, origin/tags/15thRelease, origin/tags/9thRelease, origin/tags/17thRelease, origin/tags/14thRelease, origin/tags/11thRelease, origin/tags/20thRelease, origin/tags/8thRelease, origin/tags/13thRelease, origin/tags/10thRelease, origin/tags/21stRelease, origin/tags/19thRelease, origin/tags/12thRelease, origin/tags/16thRelease, refs/tags/fb-bin1, refs/tags/15thRelease, refs/tags/13thRelease, refs/tags/8thRelease, refs/tags/19thRelease, refs/tags/16thRelease, refs/tags/12thRelease, refs/tags/17thRelease, refs/tags/9thRelease, refs/tags/21stRelease, refs/tags/11thRelease, refs/tags/10thRelease, refs/tags/20thRelease, refs/tags/14thRelease)
using credential 7cbf657e-010a-40fd-ad76-0813e675c188
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repositories
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/<user>/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<user>/repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<user>/repo.git +refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/* # timeout=10
Polling for changes in
Seen branch in repository origin/bin
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/10thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/11thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/12thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/13thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/14thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/15thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/16thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/17thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/19thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/20thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/21stRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/22ndRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/23rdRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/24thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/2ndLatest
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/3rdRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/4thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/5thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/6thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/7thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/8thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/9thRelease
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/Latest
Seen branch in repository origin/tags/fb-bin1
Seen 26 remote branches
 > git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
Done. Took 1.6 sec
No changes
```

Thanks in advance!